# Passing data to CGI script after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cgi, payment-processing

I'm unable to find a solution to this question, although I am aware it may be because it is a pretty simple one.. Nevertheless, I'd really appreciate some help.
I have a custom-built payment processing plugin (for CCBill) on a client's Wordpress site. After an initial membership payment, users can choose to make additional donations in any amount, which are directed through CCBill's ChargeByPreviousTransactionID system, so they don't have to enter their card details again.
The plugin checks to see if the user has an existing transaction and pulls the relevant data from the database. Then when they enter an amount and submit the form it constructs a query string, and then loads this as the url of a pop up window.

This causes two specific problems for us:

- most browsers block the pop up, &
- the IP address submitting the query must be whitelisted at the payment processor for the payment to go through - this should be the IP of the site, but with the pop-up window it appears to be the user's IP, which we can't whitelist

Is there a way to pass this data to the script, without opening a pop up, or having users leave our site?
I can't get the original developer to fix this issue, and I would really like to improve my programming skills by being able to fix it myself.

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
function shortcode_function(  ) 
{
    $detailsid='';
    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {
        global $current_user;

        $detailsid = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'get_donate_details_id', true );
        $detailsmoney = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'get_donate_details_price', true );
        if($detailsid!=''&& isset($_POST['wq_re_donate_now']))
        {

        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var url="https://bill.ccbill.com/jpost/billingApi.cgi?clientAccnum=900000&username=test123&password=test123&action=chargeByPreviousTransactionId&newClientAccnum=900000&newClientSubacc=0000&sharedAuthentication=1&initialPrice=<?php echo number_format($_POST['wq_amount']); ?>&initialPeriod=365&recurringPrice=0&recurringPeriod=0&rebills=0&subscriptionId=<?php echo $detailsid; ?>&currencyCode=840";

            var myWindow =window.open(url, "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }

if($detailsid!='')
    {
            ?>
    <div class="donateholder">
    <div class="donateheader"><h4>Make Donation</h4></div>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <div class="donatediv" align="left">
    <h3>Amount: &#36;<input maxlength="4" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" size="5" class="amount" name="wq_amount" id="randomnumber" />
    <input type="submit" name="wq_re_donate_now" value="Submit"  />
    </h3></div>
    </form>
    </div>
<?php
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Probably unrelated but you are not closing the `php` before the last block of `html`, or was this copy/paste issue?

Comment: Yes, sorry - that was my copy/paste-ing; it's correct in the original code.

Comment: In relation to your issue, so as of right now when the user donates (for e.g.) a `javascript` windows pops open and what does that window display? the form to enter in card details? EDIT just reread your question, so if it already has the users details what displays for them?

Comment: instead of using a popup window have you considered just opening a new tab or even using the same window as the site and just redirect back after successful payment?

Comment: Thanks for the response - with the pop up window, the user sees a blank page with the response data from the script: a numeric code for success or failure and an error message if it was not successful. But this is not designed to be seen by the user, it is data that should be captured by the site.
If I use the same window, I don't know how I would redirect back to the site, as it's the payment company's CGI script, and it doesn't seem to have this function. Also, doesn't solve the IP problem.

Comment: I'm really looking for a way to submit this data to the script without using the URL of the browser - as that seems to be what the payment processor is expecting..

Answer (score 0):

The `ChargeByPreviousTransactionID` is not meant to be invoked from the JavaScript side. You need to have a back-end server which accepts a JavaScript call done from the front-end with the necessary user-related information and then, this back-end server needs to call `bill.ccbill.com`.

This way, you can tell the CCBill Merchant Support to whitelist the IP address of your back-end server, so that you will be able to do this HTTP call. Make sure your back-end server has a static IP so that it will never change.

Remember, when you have URLs on front-end where you're hard-coding your username and password in them, that means that they need to be placed at the back-end. Like this, everyone will be able to see your username and password by inspecting the JavaScript in their browser.